Exponential map in Spin group and spin rep.
Some facts:

The connected component of the identity of $SO(1,3)$ is the physical Lorentz group $SO^{+}(1,3)$. Since the exponential map is surjective for connected Lie groups (it is diffeomorphism on to a neighborhood of identity, and a connected group is generated by any neighborhood of the identity), it follows that any matrix $\Lambda$ in that group may be written as
$$\Lambda = \exp(X) \ \ \ X \in \mathfrak{so^{+}}(1,3) = \ {A \in M_4(\mathbb{R}) | A^T = - A }$$
In physics, usually one uses a basis $M^{\rho \sigma}$ of the lie algebra and one will see something like
$$\Lambda = \exp(\Omega_{\rho \sigma} M^{\rho \sigma})$$
$Spin^+ (1,3) \subset \mathrm{Cl}(1,3)$ is a double covering of the connected Lorentz group, say by the map $\rho$. It follows that these two groups have isomorphic Lie algebras.

Question: now in physics texts, what one usually sees is something like
$$S^{\mu \nu} := \frac{1}{4} = [\gamma^\mu , \gamma^\nu] $$
where we have the Dirac gamma matrices. Then the claim is the "exponential" using these generate the spin group. Of course, this can't make sense because the spin group is not a priori a matrix group embedded in $\mathrm{Gl(4,\mathbb{R})}$!
How can I write the spin representation using the exponential map in a way that is mathematically sensible? I am looking for a reminder (proof sketch) of how to realize $lie(spin)$ as quadratic elements of the Clifford algebra, and then how to actually get a matrix to act on $\mathbb{C}^4$. i.e. via the spin representation
$$\Delta_n:Spin(1,3)→Cl(1,3)→Cl(1,3)⊗ℂ \cong \mathbb{C}l(4) \cong End(\Delta_n)$$
More precise question: if a Lorentz transform may be written as $$\Lambda = \exp(\Omega_{\rho \sigma} M^{\rho \sigma})$$,
how can we mathematically make sense of the statement that under $\Lambda$, the space $\mathbb{C}^4$ of spinors transforms as
$$\psi \to \exp(\Omega_{\rho \sigma} S^{\rho \sigma}) \psi$$

It's not always true that the exponential map is surjective for connected Lie groups. See Problem 20-6 in my Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (2nd ed.) for a counterexample.

You seem to have multiple misconceptions embedded in your question so those should be addressed first.

The fact that a connected Lie group is generated by a neighbourhood of the identity does not imply that the exponential map is surjective, so it isn't true that every element of $G$ can be written as $\exp(X)$ for some $X\in\mathfrak{g}$.
There is an exponential map $\exp:\mathfrak{g}\to G$ for any Lie group $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, not only for matrix groups.
What is $\Delta_n$? Presumably its first appearance as a map should be the spin representation and its second appearance it the spinor space.

Now, the spinor representation $\rho:\text{Spin}(p,q)\to\text{SO}(p,q)$ is given by $\rho(g)v=gvg^*$ where $g^*$ is obtained from $g$ by applying two consecutive maps on $\text{Cl}(p,q)$:

The involution $v\mapsto -v$ on $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ which induces a map $\iota:\text{Cl}(p,q)\to \text{Cl}(p,q)$
The involution $v_1\otimes\dots\otimes v_k\mapsto v_k\otimes\dots\otimes v_1$ of the tensor algebra which induces an anti-automorphism of $\text{Cl}(p,q)$

Therefore, the induced Lie algebra representation $\rho:\mathfrak{spin}(p,q)\to\mathfrak{gl}(\mathbb{R}^{p,q})$ which is obtained by differentiation is given as follows. Let $\gamma(t)=\exp(tX):I\to G$ be a curve in $G=\text{Spin}(p,q)$ such that $\gamma(0)=e$ and $\gamma'(0)=X$. Then $(\rho\circ\gamma)(t)v=\gamma(t)v\gamma(t)^*$ and
$$(\rho\circ\gamma)'(0)v = Xv + vX^*=Xv - vX$$
where the final equality uses the property of $\mathfrak{so}(p,q)$ that its elements satisfy $X^*=-X$. This follows from the fact that $\mathfrak{spin}(p,q)=\mathfrak{so}(p,q)=\wedge^2\mathbb{R}^{p,q}\subseteq\text{Cl}(p,q)$ consists of elements of degree $2$.
Thus, the exponential map gives us a spin representation $\rho:\mathfrak{spin}(p,q)\to\text{End}(\mathbb{R}^{p,q})$ explicitly, using Clifford multiplication $Xv-vX$ for $X\in\text{Cl}(p,q)$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$. Writing this down with indices and generators is a matter that I will leave you to you.

Thank you for this detailed answer: I think some miscommunication around terminology still persists though. The 2nd and 3rd points you made were already well known to me: as you comment, $\Delta_n$ is supposed to be both the space of Dirac spinors for a manifold of dimension, $n$, and by abuse of notation the Dirac spinor representation (this is a notation I learnt from Mark Hamilton's Mathematical Gauge Theory). So in the case of 4-dimensional spacetime, we want a representation of the spin group on $\mathbb{C}^4$. I'm still missing how this can be expressed via

quadratic elements of the Clifford algebra like in physics texts. See for example 4.1.1 of https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf

I have edited the question to reflect these comments.

I explained how you get a representation of $\mathfrak{spin}(p,q)$ on $\mathbb{R}^{p+q}$. By complexifying, you get a representation of $\mathfrak{spin}(p,q)$ on $\mathbb{C}^{p+q}$. As noted, $\mathfrak{spin}(p,q)$ consists precisely of the quadratic elements. So upon choosing a basis, you can work out what this looks like in index notation.

Ah, okay ~ somehow I'd never encountered spin space as a complexification of $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$.
